# How to handle use of alcohol in an interview?

Tags: interviewing, unprofessional-behavior, canada

I recently went to a job interview for a senior software developer position with a small start up. The manager and several employees (it was a panel interview) entered into the room with beers, and they all drank alcohol for the duration of the interview.

I was personally offended by their behavior, but said nothing during the interview about it.

Their ability to ask intelligent questions and engage in meaningful conversation deteriorated as the interview progressed.

Is it acceptable for interviewers to bring alcohol to an interview?

How can I end the interview quicker?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68354/discussion-on-question-by-mathew-foscarini-how-to-handle-use-of-alcohol-in-an-in).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I'm with you, Matthew - this would be a red flag for me as well.  As long as you handle the situation tactfully and respectfully, it's always OK to end an interview quickly.  In this case, it's best not to mention the alcohol.  You could say, for example, "Thanks for your consideration, but I don't think this is going to be a good fit for me.   I don't want to waste your time, so it's probably best if we cut the interview short."

The interviewers probably won't ask for details, but if they do, just politely say that the position isn't what you're looking for, and leave it at that.  You don't owe them any other explanation.

Comment: Also sounds like a great opportunity to use "no cultural fit".

Comment: I wouldn’t personally be offended. That said, I would know that it was not the place for me.

Comment: I wonder if it *may* be a good idea to mention the alcohol. One shouldn't burn bridges but sometimes there are behaviours that are completely unacceptable and telling them it was disrespectful to drink during the interview *is* acceptable, especially as they seemed to be getting drunk.

Comment: Why is it not acceptable to mention the alcohol? I think I would have said "I am sorry but you are getting drunk and this is just a waste of both our time". How is that inappropriate in this situation? I don't get it.

Answer (score 53):

> If something like this happens again in the future (and I hope it
>   doesn't). How can I best handle this, and how can I just get out of
>   the interview quicker?

Assuming you are truly that offended...

You stand up.

You say something like "Sorry. I can see this isn't the place for me. Thank you for your time."

Then you walk out and don't return.

In the past, I've cut interviews short this way when it was clear that I wouldn't accept a job offer (but for different reasons). I don't want to waste others' time and I don't want my time wasted.

> Is it acceptable to bring alcohol to an interview?

It makes no sense for you to bring alcohol to an interview. Similarly, it makes no sense for an interviewer to bring alcohol.

Comment: Agreed.  This is actually a good thing.  In most cases, you waste a lot of time on things that don't pan out.  If you can identify a poor fit early in the process then you can reclaim that time.

Comment: I've done this before.  "Sorry, I don't think I'm the right person for this job, and I don't think this is the right job for me.  Thank you for your time, but I won't take up any more of it.  Have a good afternoon."

Comment: Why would the OP not be "truly that offended"?  They state flat out that "I was personally offended".  Taking the OP at their word requires no assumptions.  Or are you trying to argue that it's actually acceptable/appropriate/professional to have some beers whilst discussing senior-level development concepts?

Comment: I've been in an interview where it was clear within 10 minutes that it wasn't a good fit; I *wish* I'd taken this approach instead of "well, I came all this way, I don't want to waste the drive." The drive was wasted either way.

Comment: lol... seriously. That was funny. I was referring to "them" bring the alcohol, but I'm absolutely sure they would have hired me if I brought my own. They might have found me more thoughtful.

Answer (score -12):

There is a reason advertising firms have wet bars. Alcohol can promote creativity. You do not say what day of the week it is. This could be any Friday afternoon in any number of shops.

It is a problem for me if the interviewee might consider themselves oppressed or intimidated because of their faith.  On a large project working around the clock, Pub time can be very productive and good for team morale. That's going to be hard if everyone else is up for it and you are not. Cultural fit. There are social norms involved, and rules. People are not inebriated, they are "tired and emotional".

But it might be offensive to people outside of that culture. It is as good as saying, we are not hiring any LDS, Muslim, Wowsers etc. today.  That is a problem.

Comment: *Alcohol can promote creativity* This is nonsense.  It promotes people being unprofessional.  If they can't be creative sober what use are they ?  And being drunk at an interview is outrageous - would they have hired a candidate who was taking alcohol to "calm their nerves" all through the interview ?  I wouldn't.  It's a ludicrous double standard.

Comment: "Alcohol can promote creativity" - So can LSD (and probably many other things).  Doesn't mean that it's a standard, appropriate, or professional way to get creative, however.  Or that the impairing side-effects can be ignored.  Though I do miss the sort of movies and music that people would create when LSD usage was at its peak.  And the OP was there for a senior dev position, not an advertising job.  Still requires creativity, yes.  But also deep focus and clear thinking.  Nobody wants a drunken codebase.

Comment: Interviewing is not a creative endeavour, and bringing alcohol into it is unprofessional, nothing more.

Comment: It seems to me that your post is an answer to another question (like "is it a problem to use alcohol in a company?"). The original question is "how can I handle this, and cut the interview short?", which you don't address at all.

Comment: @aroth, taking drugs as an aid to creativity has been an industry standard in music and poetry for hundreds of years

Comment: @Separatrix False. **False**. It is not an "industry standard" in the music industry. It has been a plague on the industry. And the musicians who haven't died because of drugs and alcohol abuse have almost universally said that the drugs do not help, instead they hinder the creative process.

Comment: Regardless of what may happen in advertising, the OP says they were going for a job as a senior software developer.  This is not acceptable behaviour in engineering.  There isn't anything necessarily wrong with a single drink at lunchtime, but if it affects your ability to work afterwards, that's not acceptable.  And drinking on work time is a definite no-no.  If they can't be professional during an interview, chances are that everything else about the company will also be unprofessional too.

Comment: Is your source [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/323/)?

Comment: @StephenG “This is nonsense” — [citation needed]. I agree that it’s completely inappropriate here and questionable in general. But regardless, it’s generally accepted (and confirmed in several studies) that use of drugs (alcohol very much included) in certain doses *does* promote creativity.

Comment: @AnderBiguri - I was thinking more [Dilbert](http://dilbert.com/strip/1992-04-06)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Perhaps you should take that view over to [Skeptics SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) because you'll find that there exist many biased studies that say many outlandish things but do not meet or even come close to scientifically acceptable.  The Dilbert study summarizes it perfectly, mine you.  I've never had a manager who wouldn't fire someone for being drunk on the job or seen a court where someone won an unfair dismissal case claiming "drink improved their creativity".  YMMV, of course - especially if you've had a couple.

Comment: @StephenG Right, but in this case there’s no real reason to doubt the veracity of the studies *a priori* as there are several, and they appear to confirm the documented prior (namely that it does have an effect). For what it’s worth, this has already been asked on Skeptics.SE, though the sole answer isn’t particularly enlightening, as it only cites a single, badly done study (out of more that exist). At any rate, a Google Scholar search is more productive than looking on Skeptics.SE in this case.

Comment: *there’s no real reason to doubt the veracity of the studies a priori* It's called common sense.  Any study claiming that alcohol improves your work has an enormous hill of common sense to climb.

Comment: @aroth as far as I have read, the OP was not drinking. You will find that many startups are run as dictatorships, so the owners and the stakeholders dictate the norms. The hires keep their heads down and work around it without making it their personal crusade to change things. It as not that long ago that foodstuffs were thought of in the same way, as was not wearing a white coat.